# UITableview not showing content first time

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I face one issue of displaying data in the `table view`. It works fine when I scrolling down and back to the top. I have also table reload in the main queue but it's not working for me. I have referred following link but not getting any solution.
 
[showing-first-time-only-when-scrolling-a-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588241/uitableview-not-showing-first-time-only-when-scrolling-a-bit) 
 [Table view cells showing actual data only after scrolling once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505598/table-view-cells-showing-actual-data-only-after-scrolling-once/38539320?noredirect=1#comment90807190_38539320)

I have also reloaded table `viewdidapear` and also when I got data from the API.

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tblDashboard.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                        self.tblDashboard.reloadData()
  }
```

Please find the attached video for the understanding ([click here for video](https://files.fm/u/q99c7h5k)) and please see the code files [here](https://files.fm/u/h27wfauk).

Comment: In the `viewDidAppear` do you already have data for the table or are you waiting an async request to get them? The code you posted where is located?

Comment: Is cellforRow trigger when you first time scroll ??

Possible Error : 
1. time takes while reload show actiity indicator for while and reload.
2. valid array
3. value not assign to row instance.

Comment: Show your full code for the tableView, show how you are getting data

Comment: try to add `cell setneedlayout` after image download in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: Okay, I will show my code.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Kindly check it.

Comment: @ilesh Code link is broken, can you please re-check it.

Comment: @BhavinKansagara, Thanks for your reply, Please check it again I have updated.

Comment: try with `self.setNeedsDisplay` method in cell after update text and image.

Comment: @Vivek, not working. :(

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your reply, But I didn't get any solution. I will be appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Strange !!**

```
 if let aTempArr = result["songs"] as? [[String : Any]] {
       //// parsing code here ......

      self.tblDashboard.reloadData() ///<---
 }
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.tblDashboard.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
      self.tblDashboard.reloadData()
 }
```

Also, I move the cell method's code into the `cellForRowAt indexPath` in Tableview controller.